# Android Support Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Доброго времени суток. Возникла такая проблема, что в eclipse всё время вылезает ошибка:

```html
[2017-01-29 20:56:28 - HelloAndroid] J:\JAVA\eclipse\HelloAndroid\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
<br>
[2017-01-29 20:56:28 - HelloAndroid] <br>
[2017-01-29 20:56:28 - HelloAndroid] J:\JAVA\eclipse\HelloAndroid\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.<br>
[2017-01-29 20:56:28 - HelloAndroid] <br>
[2017-01-29 20:56:28 - HelloAndroid] J:\JAVA\eclipse\HelloAndroid\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.<br>
[2017-01-29 20:56:28 - HelloAndroid]
```

После чего, пошел на форумы искать как же решить эту проблему. Испробовал разные варианты. После чего наткнулся на серию статей, что через Android SDK Manager надо установить Android Support Library. Но проблема заключается в том, что у меня нет такой опции в SDK Manager.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно еще решить эту проблему?

Comment: Лучшим вариантом будет отказаться от Eclipse и переходить на AndroidStudio - Eclipse более не поддерживается для андроида

Comment: я сам пользуюсь eclipse, но в Android Studio весь этот суппорт добавляется градлом из коробки, создаешь проект и он уже есть, так что рекомендую сперва ее глянуть затем самому думать откуда брать для эклипса, это должен быть проект appcompat-v7, в нем jar и ресурсы, это и есть библиотека